# How to show out of stock accosiative product of configrable product

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, out-of-stock

How can i show all options of configurable products even if any (associative) product is out of stock, it should show the option but not selectable

[image]

Comment: This seems to be an issue with Magento2.1.9.  I've been waiting on this as well, as the old fix no longer works.